# can we do multivariate regression under decision tree regression in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

I am doing a decision tree regression in python. However the predicted target values corresponding to the test sample are coming out to be mean of the target variable in that leaf. Is there a way that instead of obtaining just a mean value, we can run multivariate regression in that bucket to get the estimated value of target variable for test sample?

P.S.: Would like to know a functionality in python for something like this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2640479_Employing_Linear_Regression_in_Regression_Tree_Leaves

Comment: The data I am dealing with has quite high variability within each leaf. Hence to get a better prediction, I was trying to, say define a multivariate regression, within each tree. This will improve my predictability a lot instead of using just mean of the leaf as prediction

Comment: are you using a specific library?

Comment: I am using sklearn.tree's DecisionTreeRegressor

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that instead of obtaining just a mean value, we can run multivariate regression in that bucket to get the estimated value of target variable for test sample?

May be you should use [`sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) function to do cross-validation which can give you a number of scores:

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
>>> from sklearn.metrics.scorer import make_scorer
>>> from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
>>> X = diabetes.data[:150]
>>> y = diabetes.target[:150]
>>> lasso = linear_model.Lasso()
>>> scores = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3,
...                         scoring=('r2', 'neg_mean_squared_error'),
...                         return_train_score=True)
>>> print(scores['test_neg_mean_squared_error'])      
[-3635.5... -3573.3... -6114.7...]
>>> print(scores['train_r2'])                         
[0.28010158 0.39088426 0.22784852]
```

Comment: umm.. thing is, I am more worried about the predictions. I want to use regression within leaf to give better predictions in decision tree rather than obtaining a mean value from that bucket as prediction for all the test cases falling into that bucket.